# Unit testing Freemarker template

Tags: unit-testing, maven, freemarker

I have a Freemarker template that I would like to create a test for. The test renders the freemarker template using some mock information. I would like to render the template to an external file so that I can eyeball the results (make sure the html is aligned, etc).

I am using a traditional maven project structure for this project. Does anyone have any suggestions on what would be the most appropriate directory to output this temporary test file from my unit test?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to output it to somewhere underneath the maven ${basedir}/target directory.  You can then clean it up as part of `mvn clean`.

Comment: That's the approach I took. I created a unit-test directory under target and I create a subdirectory under that based on unitTestClass.getClass().getSimpleName().